# Paginate child models Kaminari on rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

I have 2 models `images` and `categories`.

The relations are:

**- a image belongs to one category.**

**- a category has many images.**

On the `index.html.erb` view from `categories` object, I want paginate 20 images per page for all categories.

I mean, I want paginate all images from all categories with 20 images per page.

in my `index action` on `categories_controller.rb` method I have:

```
def index
    @categories = Category.all
    @categories.each do |category| 
     @images = Kaminari.paginate_array(category.images).page(1).per(1)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @categories }
    end
   end
```

on index.html.erb I have:

```
<% @images.each do |image|%>

code for each image here

<% end %>  
<% paginate @images %>
```

But this for me it does not works. I can not see anything image showed.

**how I can implement this functionality? and fix this problem?** Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@categories.each do |category| 
  @images = Kaminari.paginate_array(category.images).page(1).per(1)
end
```

In this loop, you're overriding @images each time, so obviously, you wont get what you expect ;)

I think that what you wanna do is:

```
@images = Image.where("category_id IS NOT NULL").page(params[:page]).per(20)
```

The `.where("category_id IS NOT NULL")` is not necessary if images have to belong to a category.